# Easiest way to search replace with regex groups in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a regex that has one capturing group. Is there an easy way in scala to replace this capturing group with a replacement string? I've only been able to find functionality for replacing an entire regex with some content, which may include a capturing group, but the full regex match is not included in the replaced string. To give a concrete example:

```
val p = """^[bf]oo: '(.*)'"""r
println(p.replaceFirstGroup("foo: 'replace me'", "asdf")) // something like this
```

with output

```
foo: 'asdf'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lookahead and lookbehind (as defined for [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)), along with [`String.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) would give you the desired results:

```
val p = """(?<=^[bf]oo: ').*(?=')"""
println("foo: 'replace me'".replaceFirst(p, "asdf"))
// => foo: 'asdf'
```

The lookahead `(?=)` and lookbehind `(?<=)` both match text without including it as part of the match result. This is why `replaceFirst` only replaces the part *not* included in the lookahead or lookbehind, i.e. the `.*` between the single quote marks.

Alternatively (and I'd probably prefer this solution), you can match all of the pieces, and reference the pieces that you want to leave unchanged in the replacement string using the `$`*`{group-id}`* syntax:

```
val p = """(^[bf]oo: ')(.*)(')"""
println("foo: 'replace me'".replaceFirst(p, "$1asdf$3"))
// => foo: 'asdf'
```

I know that's not technically replacing the *first* capture group, but lookahead and lookbehind always make me feel dirty. (I know, ironic right? We're already using regular expressions here!)

---

> I was hoping to come up with something else since the lookahead limits the complexity of the regex that is in the lookahead portion and matching many groups adds extra complexity to the extractors and replacement code.

This is a bit more cumbersome to implement (you have to write some extra code), but it would keep your extractors uncluttered while also avoiding lookaheads/lookbehinds:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

implicit class MyRegExOps(val pattern: Regex) extends AnyVal {
  def replaceFirstGroup(target: String, replacement: String): Option[String] = {
    for (matched <- pattern.findFirstMatchIn(target))
      yield "%s%s%s".format(
        matched.group(0).substring(0, matched.start(1)),
        replacement,
        matched.group(0).substring(matched.end(1)))
  }
}

// Notice that the next two lines exactly match your original post
val p = """^[bf]oo: '(.*)'"""r
println(p.replaceFirstGroup("foo: 'replace me'", "asdf"))
// => Some(foo: 'asdf')
```

Comment: Ha, I came up with exactly these same two solutions as workarounds. I was hoping to come up with something else since the lookahead limits the complexity of the regex that is in the lookahead portion and matching many groups adds extra complexity to the extractors and replacement code.

Comment: @jonderry - Added another possible approach you can mull over.

Comment: Surprisingly awkward. Let me get this straight, I can replace whole patterns, but to replace groups, I have to do arithmetic?  I haven't done arithmetic since I passed the A.P. Arithmetic exam.

Comment: @som-snytt - *You* don't have to do any arithmetic (if that's what you want to call dividing strings into substrings) because I already wrote that part! But yes, if you want to manipulate a matched string *without* using multiple capture groups, you're going to be stuck doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`replaceSomeIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@replaceSomeIn%28target%3aCharSequence,replacer%3ascala.util.matching.Regex.Match=%3EOption%5BString%5D%29%3aString) method might be helpful here?

(quoting their example from ScalaDoc):

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex._

val map = Map("x" -> "a var", "y" -> """some $ and \ signs""")
val text = "A text with variables %x, %y and %z."
val varPattern = """%(\w+)""".r
val mapper = (m: Match) => map get (m group 1) map (quoteReplacement(_))
val repl = varPattern replaceSomeIn (text, mapper)
```

In your case:

```
val p = """^([bf]oo): '(.*)'"""r
val map = Map("foo" -> "foo: 'asdf'")
val lines = List("boo: 'bar' and beyond","foo: 'yuck' whatever")
val mapper = (m: Match) => map get (m group 1) map (quoteReplacement(_))

scala> val repl = text map { line => p replaceSomeIn(line, mapper) }
m: boo: 'bar' boo
m: foo: 'yuck' foo
repl: List[String] = List(boo: 'bar' and beyond, foo: 'asdf' whatever)
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this method, but it seems to involve using groups in the replacement string, not replacing a group with a replacement string.

Comment: It can be used to replace a group too it seems (if I understood right what you wanted to achieve), but I agree that it looks exotic.

Comment: Do you have a link? I couldn't find any use of this method for replacing a group.

Comment: I think the "hardcoded" mapping of foo to "foo plus replacement" is cheating. The other answer shows that the API doesn't generalize easily.